# Como criar HomePage personalizada no WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estou criando um site de classificados onde terá multisites para cada cidade diferente. Gostaria de quando acessarem minha home page, exiba somente um menu `dropdown` para o usuário escolher qual site quer acessar.

Até ai tudo bem, já tenho um plugin que cria este menu. No entanto, queria substituir a homepage original do tema, por esta home page personalizada. Alguma página em branco para que eu possa personalizar com logo e inserir o codigo PHP  que o plugin gera.

A página é do estilo das operadoras de telefonia que abre uma página pedindo para a gente escolher o estado.

Já criei um novo modelo a partir deste código:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Home Customizada */
?>
```

Porém, a página criada vai junto com os dados do tema com todo o conteúdo como `header`, menus e `footer`. Eu queria somente uma página em branco com o formulário dropdown que o plugin gera.

Segue o código do meu header.php @Matheus Ilário:

```
    <div class="header_top">

            <div class="header_top_res">

                    <p>
                            <?php echo cp_login_head(); ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo appthemes_get_feed_url(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon_rss.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="rss" class="srvicon" /></a>

                            <?php if ( get_option('cp_twitter_username') ) : ?>
                                    &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo get_option('cp_twitter_username'); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon_twitter.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="tw" class="srvicon" /></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>

            </div><!-- /header_top_res -->

    </div><!-- /header_top -->


    <div class="header_main">

            <div class="header_main_bg">

                    <div class="header_main_res">

                            <div id="logo">

                                    <?php if ( get_option('cp_use_logo') != 'no' ) { ?>

                                            <?php if ( get_option('cp_logo') ) { ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_option('cp_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="header-logo" /></a>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><div class="cp_logo"></div></a>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                    <?php } else { ?>

                                            <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
                                            <div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>

                                    <?php } ?>

                            </div><!-- /logo -->

                            <div class="adblock">
                                <?php appthemes_advertise_header(); ?>
                            </div><!-- /adblock -->

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                    </div><!-- /header_main_res -->

            </div><!-- /header_main_bg -->

    </div><!-- /header_main -->


    <div class="header_menu">

            <div class="header_menu_res">

            <a href="<?php echo CP_ADD_NEW_URL; ?>" class="obtn btn_orange"><?php _e( 'Post an Ad', APP_TD ); ?></a>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => false, 'container' => false) ); ?>

            <div class="clr"></div>


            </div><!-- /header_menu_res -->

    </div><!-- /header_menu -->
```

Código HTML do index.php

```
<div class="content_botbg">

    <div class="content_res">

        <?php
            if ( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH . '/featured.php') )
                include_once(STYLESHEETPATH . '/featured.php');
            else
                include_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured.php');
        ?>


        <!-- left block -->
        <div class="content_left">


            <?php if ( get_option('cp_home_layout') == 'directory' ) : ?>

                <div class="shadowblock_out">

                    <div class="shadowblock">

                        <h2 class="dotted"><?php _e( 'Ad Categories', APP_TD ); ?></h2>

                        <div id="directory" class="directory <?php if ( get_option('cp_cat_dir_cols') == 2 ) echo 'twoCol'; else echo 'Col'; ?>">

                            <?php echo cp_create_categories_list( 'dir' ); ?>

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                        </div><!--/directory-->

                    </div><!-- /shadowblock -->

                </div><!-- /shadowblock_out -->

            <?php endif; ?>


            <div class="tabcontrol">

                <ul class="tabnavig">
                    <li><a href="#block1"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Just Listed', APP_TD ); ?></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#block2"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Most Popular', APP_TD ); ?></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#block3"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Random', APP_TD ); ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>

                <?php
                    remove_action( 'appthemes_after_endwhile', 'cp_do_pagination' );
                    if ( get_option('permalink_structure') == '' )
                        $post_type_url = add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'paged' => 2 ), site_url('/') );
                    else
                        $post_type_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/'.get_option('cp_post_type_permalink').'/page/2/';
                ?>


                <!-- tab 1 -->
                <div id="block1">

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <div class="undertab"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Classified Ads', APP_TD ); ?> / <strong><span class="colour"><?php _e( 'Just Listed', APP_TD ); ?></span></strong></span></div>

                    <?php
                        // show all ads but make sure the sticky featured ads don't show up first
                        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
                        $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) );
                    ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' ); ?>

                    <?php
                        if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
                    ?>
                            <div class="paging"><a href="<?php echo $post_type_url; ?>"> <?php _e( 'Ver mais', APP_TD ); ?> </a></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div><!-- /block1 -->


                <!-- tab 2 -->
                <div id="block2">

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <div class="undertab"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Classified Ads', APP_TD ); ?> / <strong><span class="colour"><?php _e( 'Most Popular', APP_TD ); ?></span></strong></span></div>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'featured' ); ?>

                    <?php
                        global $cp_has_next_page;
                        if ( $cp_has_next_page ) {
                            $popular_url = add_query_arg( array( 'sort' => 'popular' ), $post_type_url );
                    ?>
                            <div class="paging"><a href="<?php echo $popular_url; ?>"> <?php _e( 'Ver mais', APP_TD ); ?> </a></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                </div><!-- /block2 -->


                <!-- tab 3 -->
                <div id="block3">

                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <div class="undertab"><span class="big"><?php _e( 'Classified Ads', APP_TD ); ?> / <strong><span class="colour"><?php _e( 'Random', APP_TD ); ?></span></strong></span></div>

                    <?php
                        // show all random ads but make sure the sticky featured ads don't show up first
                        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'rand' ) );
                        $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) );
                    ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' ); ?>

                    <?php
                        if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
                            $random_url = add_query_arg( array( 'sort' => 'random' ), $post_type_url );
                    ?>
                            <div class="paging"><a href="<?php echo $random_url; ?>"> <?php _e( 'Ver mais', APP_TD ); ?> </a></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div><!-- /block3 -->


            </div><!-- /tabcontrol -->

        </div><!-- /content_left -->


        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>


        <div class="clr"></div>

    </div><!-- /content_res -->

</div><!-- /content_botbg -->
```

Comment: Olá Renato, seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Você precisa especificar melhor o problema, e juntar o código que está com problema. Aparentemente, o assunto de sua pergunta não está dentro do escopo do SOpt. Ainda editei pra aparecer o pequeno código que postou, mas acho que não vai adiantar. Para questões sobre personalização de templates, sugiro que procure um fórum específico. Para entender quais assuntos são on topic, leia este tópico http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic. Se achar que sua pergunta está no escopo, tente reformulá-la.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, tente criar outro arquivo header.php para a página principal, por exemplo header-home.php seguindo a documentação http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: Por favor não usem comentários para discussões prolongadas. A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23890/discussion-on-answer-by-matheus-ilario-como-criar-homepage-personalizada-no-word).